# Why perl regex '*?' stay greedy?

Tags: regex, perl

I run a simple program:

```
my $_ =  '/login/.htaccess/.htdf';
s!(/\.ht.*?)$!/!;
print "$_ $1";
```

**OUT**
`/login/ /.htaccess/.htdf`

I want this regex to match only `/.htdf`.

Example 2:

```
my $_ =  'abcbc';
m/(b.*?)$/;
print "$_ $1\n";
```

**OUT**
`abcbc bcbc`

I expect `bc`.

Why is `*?` still greedy? (I want the minimal match.)

Comment: Regex's are a LEFT to RIGHT bias. _Minimal_ means find the FIRST one. So it finds the first `b` then matches the rest of the line because of `.*?$`

Comment: Fyi, the way you are using it, `.*?$` is exactly equivalent to `.*` I.e. they are both greedy.

Comment: You are actually specifying that you want to capture *everything* before the end of the line. So it either matches everything, or it fails, and regexes will match where they can.

Comment: The `\K` is useless in `s{\K/\.ht[^/]*$}{}`. If you don't want a trailing `/`, use `s{/\.ht[^/]*$}{}`.

Comment: It there switch in perlre from LEFT-RIGHT  to RIGHT-LEFT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Atoms are matched in sequence, and each atom after the first must match at the position where the previous atom left off matching. (The first atom is implicitly preceded by `\A(?s:.)*?`.) That means that `.*`/`.*?` doesn't get to decided where it starts matching; it only gets to decided where it stops matching.

### Example 1

It's not being greedy. `\.ht` brings the match to position 10, and *at position 10*, the minimum `.*?` can match and still have the rest of the pattern match is `access/.htdf`. In fact, it's the only thing `.*?` can match *at position 10* and still have the rest of the pattern match.

I think you want to remove that last part of the path if it starts with `.ht`, leaving the preceding `/` in place. For that, you can use either of the following:

```
s{/\.ht[^/]*$}{/}
```

or

```
s{/\K\.ht[^/]*$}{}
```

### Example 2

It's not being greedy. `b` brings the match to position 2, and *at position 2*, the minimum `.*?` can match and still have the rest of the pattern match is `cbc`. In fact, it's the only thing `.*?` can match *at position 2* and still have the rest of the pattern match.

You are probably looking for

```
/b[^b]*$/
```

or

```
/b(?:(?!b).)*$/    # You'd use this if "b" was really more than one char.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead for this:

```
~/(\.ht(?!.*\.ht).*)$~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nH8aC1/2)

`(?!.*\.ht)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure there is no `.ht` occurrence after `.ht` thus making sure only last `.ht` is matched.

`.*?` will be non-greedy if there is some pattern after this on right hand.

**Code:**

```
$str = '/login/.htaccess/.htdf';

$str =~ s~/(\.ht(?!.*\.ht).*)$~/~m;

print "$str\n";
```

Comment: `(?!.*\.ht)` is very error-prone. (e.g. It'll break if you add `/s` to that pattern.) `(?:(?!\.ht).)` is far more robust.

Comment: Yes agreed, but that is true ONLY if input is multiline and `s` is also used otherwise `(?:(?!\.ht).)` will be lot more slower than `(?!.*\.ht)`

Comment: No, it'll break in plenty of other cases. In fact, it's extremely rare that you can use the pattern you used at all.

Comment: **it'll break in plenty of other cases** Would like to learn those cases.

Comment: Provide some example input please

Comment: Intent is not to match `abc` but last `a`

Comment: I think that's where disconnect is. My intent was to get the **last** match in a single line.

Comment: Yes I did and so far I could not see where `(?!.*a)` will not match last `a` in a single line.

Comment: Right and as I said that's the problem I was targeting to solve i.e. to match last occurrence of a text in a single line.

Comment: Whatever it is this is the problem I targeted in my answer. Whether I interpreted question correctly or not that is another debate.

Comment: You can keep your opinion but no I didn't see any clear case where this regex will fail to match last occurrence of a text in a single line.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't work in the very narrow and specific case of the OP's problem; I said it was error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't it? The greediness is in the forward direction, not backwards. In non-greedy mode, the state machine starts matching and does the check at every step instead of just munching it all and then backtrack, but this does not guarantee you of the "minimal match".

Maybe you might want to avoid matching `/`? Like in `s{/\.ht[^/]*$}{/}`.

Answer (score 0):

The regex works like you've made it.
But if you want to use the dot metacharacter, it must be greedy.

This should work `s!.*/\K\.ht.*$!!` It basically lops off the end `.ht...`

If you want to be specific, you'd need `s!/\K\.htdf$!!`